# heightForRowAtIndexPath row index does not match cellForRowAtIndexPath row index

Tags: ios

**Resolved:**
*I've figured this out, sorry - silly mistake on my part. Basically my table had no separators with each of my cells having a custom border on the bottom. This border wasn't being repositioned correctly in the taller cell making the cell after it look taller. It was obvious once I selected a cell and the selection background appeared.*

I have an interesting problem with hopefully an obvious solution or explanation.

I have a UITableView that should have 10 rows of equal heights but the first cell should slightly higher than the rest.

I have the following code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {

    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {    

    return indexPath.row == 0 ? defaultCellHeight + 20 : defaultCellHeight;
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                    //text = First Row Text
                break;
            default:
                    //text = something else
                break;
    }

    //return some sort of cell here
}
```

Now the issue I am seeing is that the second row is being made higher than the rest, not the first as I would expect. Any ideas why this is?

I assume it is something to do with the first row being considered a header or something but can't find a way around it. Subsequent indexes are also consequentially 1 lower than I would expect.

Comment: please paste full code, I tried but it seems to be no problem with the above code

Comment: Did you add a header view at all? Or section headers? The code above looks fine so far. The problem must be somewhere else. A screenshot may be helpful too.

Comment: I've figured this out, sorry - silly mistake on my part. Basically my table had no separators with each of my cells having a custom border on the bottom. This border wasn't being repositioned correctly in the taller cell making the cell after it look taller. It was obvious once I selected a cell and the selection background appeared.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {    

if ([indexPath row] == 0)
return defaultCellHeight + 20
else
return defaultCellHeight

 }
```

Tested it out and worked for me